# what do you call a symmetric vector like {1,2,4,4,2,1}

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm so sorry to ask this basic question, but what is the term for a vector (list) such as {1,2,4,4,2,1}, which is the same when you reverse order?.  I used to know the term for this.  How about {1,2,4,-4,-2-1}.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: palindrome?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I thought of this, palindrome.  However, the term doesn't seem to be used in a mathematical context.  I know there is a word for this in math, but I can't remember it.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Still, it could be called that, at least informally. As an alternative, perhaps "left-right symmetry".

Comment: Fair enough, it could be called that.  However, these palindrome vectors have nice properties when you multiply them by symmetric matrixes. I think people have written about these properties.  In order to find this literature, I need to be able to search for the proper mathematica term.

Comment: For example, I think that if you multiply a palindrome vector by a symmetric matrix, you still get a palindrome vector.

Comment: That's not true. For example, take a $2{\times}2$ diagonal matrix $A$ with diagonal entries $1,2$, and compute $Av$ where $v=\langle{1,1}\rangle$.

Comment: Of course.  My bad.  But in any case, I remember there were some interesting properties about palindrome vectors and  symmetric matrixes.  I'd like to find them again.

Comment: It's clear that the set of palindromic vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also if $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is a palindromic column vector, then $v v^T$ is a symmetric $n{\times}n$ matrix.

Comment: I have never come across a name for this type of vector.